# dc.js - Tooltips adding another item?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

If I have the following data -

```
item        count   type
----------------------------------
apple      1        fruit
orange     2        fruit
carrot     1        vegetable
apple      2        fruit
```

I then have the following Dimension and Group

```
var itemDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d.item;});
var itemDimGroup = itemDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.count; });
```

The tool tips of my row chart displaying this data has the item and the count.

My question is whether it's possible to add the `type` to the tool tip as well?

For example the tool tip would hold the following (the type would only be one value for each item) -

```
apple's : 3
type : fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a title:

```
           .title(function (p) {

                return [
                       p.value.item + " : " + p.value.count,
                       "type: " + p.value.type
                       ]
                       .join("\n");
            })
           .renderTitle(true)
```

**Edit:**

```
var itemDimGroup = itemDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return [
            d.count,
            d.key
            ]
             .join("\n");
});


barChart
  .width(300)
  .height(200)

  .transitionDuration(500)
  .dimension(itemDim)
  .group(itemDimGroup)
  .brushOn(false)
  .barPadding(0.2)
  .xAxisLabel("")
  .yAxisLabel("")
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
  .title(function (p) {
    console.log(p);
    return [
             p.key + " : " + String(p.value),
            "type: " + p.key
            ]
             .join("\n");
            })
  .renderTitle(true)
;
```

Comment: I've tried this and I'm getting 'undefined', I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/northside45/gqkak743/1/

Comment: Hi, in your fiddle it doesn't show the type, just the item and count. I'm not sure how to add the "type: " + p.value.type?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gqkak743/4/  .... here is the best I can do, there is probably a cleaner way.

Comment: Hi that's great! However I then add another chart it seems to cause problems. Is there a way round this? See here - http://jsfiddle.net/northside45/gqkak743/20/

Comment: The issue is that the hack in my last fiddle applies a filter to the piechart. This is an issue but you can try to continue hacking away and adding .... pieChart.filterAll(); ... in between the charts to clear the filter on load.